# network will not work properly after having run TCP optimizer, but safe mode settings work perfectly. how to restore?

Tags: windows-7, tcpip, safe-mode, netsh, connection

I was experiencing some issues with my connection while playing online and I tried to optimize it by running TCP optimizer on my PC (Windows 7 64bit professional). I thought maybe the situation could improve.
but it didn't.

actually, I now get an extremely slow page loading time, probably due to a very low RWIN value of 1024.
I understand that Windows 7 has a system to automatically adjust the RWIN value when needed. The setting from netsh is "normal" so I guess something else must be wrong.

I tried every automatic tool out there to restore Windows' default values, but I had no success. I currently have what should be labeled as "default values" for everything TCP Optimizer initially changed, but the problem persists.

The thing is, I just found out that running Windows in safe mode SOLVES the problem completely. The problem is that as soon as I reboot, I get the same issue all over again.

So my question is: *is there a way to use SAFE MODE network settings in NORMAL mode?*

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following command in an elevated command prompt (right click "Command Prompt", choose Run As Administrator):

```
netsh winsock reset
```

If that doesn't work, try restoring to a date before you ran the optimizer using System Restore.

==EDIT==

I found some more ideas.  Try running the following command in an elevated command prompt:

```
netsh int ip reset
```

followed by `netsh winsock reset`, then reboot.

If you still have issues, try:

```
netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=Normal
netsh int tcp set global congestionprovider=default
netsh int tcp set heuristics default
netsh int tcp set global ecncapability=default
netsh int tcp set global dca=disabled
```

Also check [this link](http://www.nvnews.net/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=93371) for ideas to get your speed up once you get your system running properly (mostly router tweaks)

Comment: Thanks. I've just tried it, but it didn't work. I had already tried system restore, luckily I had a restore point from yesterday, but nothing changes (except I have to reinstall an adobe flash update :-( )

Comment: I just updated my answer with some more information I found.